# A way to do linear regression in single variable

Tags: linear-regression

Can we do linear regression the following way:
1. Split the given batch into small batches of three points each.
2. Find the centroids of each batch.
3. Do the linear regression in these points.

Comment: This sounds very similar to the Theil-Sen estimator for robust regression. It is possible that your regression software or programming language has already implemented the Theil-Sen estimator.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't knew it earlier. Sounds interesting.